# cpack -B build/ fails in parent directory

Tags: deb, cpack

I want to make a Debian package using [cpack](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CPack.html).

I want to stay in `base_folder/`. It contains a source folder `src/` and a `build/` folder with temporary build files and build artifacts:

```
base_folder$ ls
build src
```

I try to make the package

```
base folder$ cpack -B build/
CPack Error: CPack generator not specified
```

But if I go to `build/` then it works OK:

```
cd build/
cpack
```

How I can use `cpack` without `cd build/`?

This is [my example](https://github.com/AndreiCherniaev/cpack_outside_of_build_folder) to reproduce...
cmake version 3.26.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be

```
cpack --config build/CPackConfig.cmake -B build/
```

I have updated [my example](https://github.com/AndreiCherniaev/cpack_outside_of_build_folder). Now works good.